# shouldChangeTextIn terminating if out of range, how to guard/check if out of range

Tags: swift, nsstring, core-text

I am using -

```
shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange  -
```

to change text in  3 labels as I am typing.
If I change from label to label two quickly while the text is still updating I get a crash with the following error

is there a check I can put into the function to make sure I am within range or the index exists?

```
2018-03-24 09:51:05.024557+0000 textinput3[24714:952788] ***     

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 
'-    [__NSCFString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]: Range or     
index out of bounds'
```

this is the function.

```
    func textView(_ textField: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText string: String) -> Bool {
    if field?.tag == 1 {
        updatedText = ((field?.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string))!
    }
    if field?.tag == 2 {
        updatedTitleText = ((field?.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string))!

    }
    if field?.tag == 3 {            
        updatedCaptionText = ((field?.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string))!

    }

    return true
}
```

(there is a slight lag between typing the characters and the characters appearing, so the crash happens if I change to another label while the previous label is still updating)

Comment: Do you have a solution for it?